# Shipping regions and range for WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have 3 zones where i can ship my products UK, Europe, Rest of world, and each zone, i only have 48 products in my store. I need to set up a different shipping cost according to the zone BUT each zone will have 4 or 5 different shipping prices. How can i achieve this? This should be something easy, i might be confused. Should i use shipping class?

For example:
Product A UK - 4£ EU - 8£ Rest- 9£ 
Product B UK - 2£ EU - 6£ Rest- 7£ 
Product C UK - 5£ EU - 9£ Rest- 12£

Comment: **You can do that without any code** using **Shipping classes…** So if your have 3 different products shipping rates, you will need to create 3 shipping classes. Then to set in each shipping zone the correct rate for each shipping class… Once done, you sill need to set the correct shipping class to each product. So you should read related WooCommerce documentation.

Comment: Lovely, thank you for the clarification. Now i understood how it should work.